# Sharing Data Across Services in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I've looked around a bit but there seems to be no material on sharing data between services in Angular2. I have two @Injectable() services, where one is a Singleton that broadcasts data. In the other service, I have code that updates a variable called progress as a web audio track plays:

```
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

...

@Injectable()
export class WebAudioTrack implements IAudioTrack {
  public _progress: number = 0;
  ...
  constructor(public src: string, @Optional() public preload: string = 'none', @Optional() private ctx: AudioContext = undefined ) {
    // audio context not needed for now
    // this.ctx = this.ctx || new AudioContext();
    this.createAudio(); 
  }
  private onTimeUpdate(e: Event) {
    if (this.isPlaying && this.audio.currentTime > 0) {
      # I want to do something like SharedService.setProgress(this.audio.currentTime) here
      this._progress = this.audio.currentTime;
      this._completed = this.audio.duration > 0 ? Math.trunc (this.audio.currentTime / this.audio.duration * 100)/100 : 0;
    }  
  }
```

I'm looking for a way to broadcast the _progress variable in the code above to another @Injectable called SharedService. I don't even need to set up a BehaviorSubject in the code above because I should just be able to do something like SharedService.setProgress(time) every time the onTimeUpdate fires.

The question is, how can I add the SharedService to the code above? When I try to add it to the constructor it complains because there are calls to "new WebTrackAudio(variable, variable)". Here's the other service code which is incomplete and might be slightly confusing:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    progress: number;

    setProgress(progress: number) {
        console.log(progress);
        this.progress = progress;
    }
    getProgress() {
        return this._webTrack._progress;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

When I update the constructor in the first service to include SharedService like so:

```
  constructor(public src: string, @Optional() public preload: string = 'none', @Optional() private ctx: AudioContext = undefined, public sharedService: SharedService ) {
    // audio context not needed for now
    // this.ctx = this.ctx || new AudioContext();
    this.createAudio(); 
  }
```

I get the following error:

Typescript Error

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
>
> .../src/app/ionic-audio/ionic-audio-providers.ts
>
> create(track: ITrackConstraint) {
>
> let audioTrack = new WebAudioTrack(track.src, track.preload);
>
> Object.assign(audioTrack, track);

Comment: I'm sure to get to the core of the problem you could remove 2/3 of the code. I find it quite confusing what the problem actually is from all the noise. To share data between services you can just inject a service into another as long as you don't cause circular dependencies.

Comment: What do you mean with "adding to the constructor"? Why would you need a call to `new WebTrackAudio(variable, variable)` if it is a service?

Comment: I actually removed about 90% of the code already (you can see the ...s).

I guess it's not a service? What is it then?

I'm still getting my feet wet with angular2

Comment: It's not a Singleton service but I think it's still a service... correct me if I'm wrong though

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer How do I inject a service into another?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. A service is a class that is provided in `providers: [...]` of an `@NgModule()` or `@Component()` and injected to a constructor of a service, component, directive, or pipe. Where you provide it determins if it will be a singleton or not.

Comment: You inject a service into another by adding it to the constructor `class MyService1 { constructor(private service:MyService2) {} }`

Comment: Just updated the code to have less junk in it :)... okay I'll try that

Comment: Your question is now missing the constructors. The constructors are essential for dependency injection. Besides that I think reducing the code improved the question a lot :-)

Comment: I just added a TypeScript error that I get when I include it into the constructor as you suggested.. thanks for the reply below!

Comment: This constructor `constructor(public src: string, @Optional() public preload: string = 'none', @Optional() private ctx: AudioContext = undefined ) {`
doesn't make your class look like a service. If you do `new Xxx()` then `Xxx` isn't a service, it's just an a class you create an instance of, entirely unrelated to Angular (but might still be used within Angular of course)

Comment: do you know of any way of adding the service to it?

Comment: Adding service to what? Perhaps you mean injecting the service to the class that contains the code `new WebAudioTrack(track.src, track.preload);` and then pass the service like `new WebAudioTrack(track.src, track.preload, sharedService);`. There is no way to automagically get a service passed to a class instance you create with `new`.

Answer (score 2):

```ts
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

...

@Injectable()
export class WebAudioTrack implements IAudioTrack {
  public _progress: number = 0;
  ...

  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {}

  private onTimeUpdate(e: Event) {
    if (this.isPlaying && this.audio.currentTime > 0) {
      # I want to do something like this.sharedService.setProgress(this.audio.currentTime) here
      this._progress = this.audio.currentTime;
      this._completed = this.audio.duration > 0 ? Math.trunc (this.audio.currentTime / this.audio.duration * 100)/100 : 0;
    }  
  }
```

ensure both services are provided like

```ts
@NgModule({
  ...,
  providers: [WebAudioTrack, SharedService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This technique is leading me to get the following TS error: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Edited the post to reflect the details

Comment: @user2476265 you can't declare required arguments after optional ones.

Comment: Optional parameters like these don't make sense in services at all. It would be necessary to clarify how the class is actually used.